# SQLException can't delete database [database_name]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Some time when I run my c# mvc web-project

**SQLException  can't delete  database [database_name] . [database_name] is in Use**
on the line where I am try to retrieve my data from DBContextex Object . But the error is obsoleted when I deleted the database and restarting  the project . It is happening suddenly . After happening the error I restarted the project again then error still exist when ever I deleted the database and restart .
Suppose controller Action has following line

```
List<entityname> listent=new DbContext().entitynames.toList();
```

is executing then I am geeting the error on the following line . 
I have a database Initializer also.

What may be the problem ?

Comment: So, you're using Entity Framework, please elaborate on your question and post some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one of the drop-create initializers set in your constructor like below then EF will recreate the database each time the context is initialized.

```
public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbConnectionString")
{
    //TODO: Remove initializer
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
}
```

If you do want entity framework to do this then make sure that your user account has the required access in SQL Server to do this.

If your database has been created and you only want to apply updates, remove the initializer and use EF migrations instead.